# Internet Radio Device with batteries

Tags: raspbian, audio, power, ethernet, streaming

I have a project that I will make a connection with the Internet and listen to a stream (in my case *`IP:port` or `.ogg`, `.m3u` URL online radio station*) then decode the music and transmit it to speakers connected to the microcontroller.

At first, I thought that Arduino UNO can be used with an ethernet shield and mp3 decoder shield. But, after research, two shields cannot be used on it. Furthermore, a comment  that says:

> Not a chance. Even the ESP8266, which has many times the RAM and
>   processing power of a UNO requires an external RAM chip for
>   buffering. The UNO will never be able to decode the audio fast enough,
>   and it doesn't have an analog output to drive the speaker. I'd
>   recommend using a Raspberry Pi or similar. This is not a task for a
>   microcontroller.

Secondly, I thought that a Raspberry Pi could be used but I heard it doesn't work with the battery cell (in my case AA alkalines and LiOn.)

Moreover, I need a microcontroller working with battery cells and meets the expectations to build the project.

There are some similar links related to the project,

http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=85191.0

https://www.jaycollett.com/2011/07/retro-wifi-radio/

https://cassiopeia.hk/internetradio/

[Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hCott53kQvI) in action.

What would you propose to me for the project to be achieved? How can I overcome the project?

---

What about **Raspberry Pi Zero W**? If it is ok, what do I need additionally e.g. modules?

Comment: is [this](https://maniacbug.wordpress.com/2011/12/30/arduino-on-ice-internet-radio-via-shoutcast/) the sort of thing you want to create? (that's an arduino solution, so whoever told you that you can't do it with Arduino is wrong)

Comment: So do you just need to solve power for the RPi? I've seen chips that can power the RPI from 1 or multiple 18650 Lion batteries or multiple AA's.